# Encrypt and Decrypt Cookies stored in react-native Cookies database

Tags: react-native, security, encryption, cookies, fetch-api

In my react-native app, I used the `fetch` library for network communication, also I used Cookie in my communications.

My server sends me some sensitive data and I configured my fetch request to store the cookies by `credentials: 'include'`

```
fetch(URL, {
  // other Options
  credentials: 'include',
}).then().catch();
```

I tested my app on a rooted android device and figure out that the cookies have been stored within a database named `Cookies`.

[image]

when I opened the database in the SQLiteDatabase browser I figure out my sensitive data are insecurely stored in that database.

[image]

I know that fetch Api is using Okhttp3 in android implementation, so I tried to change the default client to change the default behavior by overriding its CookieJar class and add some Encryption and Decryption procedure to it.

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    OkHttpClientProvider.setOkHttpClientFactory(new OkHttpClientFactory() {
        @Override
        public OkHttpClient createNewNetworkModuleClient() {
            ReactCookieJarContainer reactCookieJarContainer = new ReactCookieJarContainer();
            reactCookieJarContainer.setCookieJar(new SecureCookieJar());
            return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                // other configures
                .cookieJar(reactCookieJarContainer)
                .build();
        }
    });
}
```

**SecureCookieJar**

```
public class SecureCookieJar implements CookieJar {

    @Override
    public void saveFromResponse(HttpUrl url, List<Cookie> cookies) {
        // securely encrypt and store the cookies
    }

    @Override
    public List<Cookie> loadForRequest(HttpUrl url) {
        // decrypt the stored cookies
    }
}
```

but when I debugging my code it seems my class does not take into account by react-native and still using its internal class `JavaNetCookieJar` (I debugged the code and reach the class blow)

**ReactCookieJarContainer** 
[image]

Is there any way to override the default behavior at all and if yes how can I achieve it. the ideal approach is finding a way to override the `JavaNetCookieJar` to encrypt and decrypt cookie before transferring them.

Is there a similar procedure needed for IOS too? I don't know how IOS manages the cookies in its native implementation.